# Blender Console stays open when exiting Blender

Tags: command-line

so whenever I close Blender, whether it be closing it when my work is saved or not, Blender itself will close with no issues, but the console window will open and stay open. The only way to close it is to click the icon and choose the close window or the Ctrl+C shortcut.
The issue isn't life-threatening, just very frustrating. The issue only started when installing the 3.1.2 version.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There is a known bug [T95727](https://developer.blender.org/T95727) that was introduced in 3.01 and closed because it was thought that a fix for another bug had solved it.  It looks like this is a regression in 3.1.2.  But there's also [T97045](https://developer.blender.org/T97045) which appears to be a problem with BlenderKit.  Are you using Blenderkit?

Comment: Ah, I am indeed using BlenderKit. I'll try uninstalling it and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Comment: might be able to get away with just disabling it in preferences.

Comment: Aand fixed. I uninstalled BlenderKit and bam, no more issue. I'll try installing at a later date but at least now I know the cause of the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  As the bug report points out, the Blenderkit developers have been informed; so hopefully they'll have a fix soon.

Comment: Just a quick update: Blenderkit has now been updated to version 3.1.1 which has cured the console window problem.